# Insert user IP Address into MYSQL Trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers

I'm creating a MYSQL Trigger.  I'd like the trigger to record the ip address of the user who initiated the database change.

Is this possible?  And if so, how can MySQL get the user's IP Addy?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot get the IP address of the user using MySQL. You do have access to the invoking user via USER(). e.g.

```
mysql> select USER();
+--------------------+
| USER()             |
+--------------------+
| hobodave@localhost | 
+--------------------+
1 row in set (0.06 sec)
```

Comment: I think you meant CURRENT_USER(), which would not work in the context of a trigger anyway. You may want to try USER() though.

Comment: You are correct with regards to it not working as expected inside a trigger, USER does however.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know which *MySQL user* initiated the database change, you can use the [USER()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_user) function, [which will return the invoking user](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/account-activity-auditing.html).

However, understand that we're talking about *MySQL user*, this has nothing to do with the web. For instance, if your application is a web-application, the address will be "localhost" or the name of your server, not the address of the person using your web application. To get their address, you'll have to do so using PHP or any equivalent language.